# Returning the result of `<<` from `operator<<`

Tags: c++, stream, overloading

All guides about `operator<<` say that you should return the output stream:

```
ostream & operator<<(ostream &os, const Foo &x) { os<<"foo"; return os; }
```

But can't it be just a bit simpler?

```
ostream & operator<<(ostream &os, const Foo &x) { return os<<"foo"; }
```

If the called `<<` follows the guides and returns its first parameter, then it should be 100% the same. But am I relying on something that isn't guaranteed? Can it fail in some case?

Why do I want it? Not just to save keystrokes (we're not in [codegolf.SE](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com))
The actual usage is a bit more complicated:

```
enum class Foo { A, B, C };
ostream & operator<<(ostream &os, const Foo &x) {
    switch (x) {
        case A: return os << "A";
        case B: return os << "B";
        case C: return os << "C";
    }
    return os << "Bad Foo (" << (int)x << ")";
}
```

The multiple returns make the code much more simple and readable (imagine 50 cases, not 3) compared to all alternatives I found. Note that the lack of `default` allows the compiler to warn about missing cases, so you won't forget to add one when adding an enum value.

Comment: Actually, you have no question (make it so)

Comment: Hmm, thought it was asked about guarentees and faster, albeit in the middle

Comment: @DieterLücking, there is a question - "am I relying on something that isn't guaranteed? Can it fail in some case?" You may have lost it, because I added text below it explaining the motivation for asking.

Comment: Very nice observation, I will keep this mind for future use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is expected to be able to chain, your simplification should work, and will fail at compilation if the offending class definition does not follow convention

Any place where

```
std::cout << a << b << std::endl;
```

would work, so would your simplification, which should suffice without a true guarentee

Specificly, the `operator <<` for string literals as in your question is guarenteed to return the correct `ostream`

Comment: Knowing that it works whenever chaining works is good enough for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the overload you're using is returning a reference, these

```
ostream & operator<<(ostream &os, const Foo &x) { os<<"foo"; return os; }
ostream & operator<<(ostream &os, const Foo &x) { return os<<"foo"; }
```

will have the same effect and allow for the usual chaining

```
cout << Foo::A << Foo::B;
```

If the first sentence were not to hold (e.g. calling some other custom-defined overload that does not return a reference to the stream object) then you would have to either explicitly return the stream reference or provide a different overload if you still wanted to chain those statements.